# Why doesn't my Python file write multiple rows in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write multiple data rows into a CSV. Executes fine in powershell, but my excel file only returns the first line of code. Assumed the "\n" would do the trick but it seems not.

Code is as follows:

```
filename = "products.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
      brand = container.div.img["title"]

      title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
      product_name = title_container[0].text

      price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
      product_price = price_container[0].text

      print("brand: " + brand)
      print("product_name: " + product_name)
      print("product_price: " + product_price)

f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Your `f.write` occurs *after* the loop, not *in* the loop. You need to indent it.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should consider using the `csv` module instead.

Comment: Add `import csv` to your code and use csv writer. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @chepner Indent worked! Thanks!

Unsure what you mean by using the CSV module instead? Sorry, very new to this. This is my first day using Python.

Comment: @chepner What does using the CSV module enable?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: CSV module makes writing CSV simple. Auto escapes and quotes the values, etc. so generates a valid CSV file. Replace f.write() with csvwriter.writerow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python's CSV library would make creating your output file easier. It takes a list of values and correctly formats it for a row in a CSV file.

For example:

```
import csv

filename = "products.csv"

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = ["brand", "product_name", "product_price"]    
    csv_output.writerow(header)    

    for container in containers:
        brand = container.div.img["title"]

        title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
        product_name = title_container[0].text

        price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
        product_price = price_container[0].text

        print("brand: " + brand)
        print("product_name: " + product_name)
        print("product_price: " + product_price)

        csv_output.writerow([brand, product_name.replace(",", "|"), product_price])
```

Also you can convert your `open()` and `close()` into a `with...` statement. The file is automatically closed after it. A `newline=''` is needed when using a csv writer to avoid extra newlines being written between rows.